# Auto mounting EFS on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-efs

I created an EC2 instance and an EFS, and was able to mount EFS properly on the instance.

I need to auto mount in case the server is rebooted.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html), i do that following in `/etc/fstab`

```
fs-xxxxxxxx:/ /mnt/efs efs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

Using the EFS file system ID in place of xxxxxxxx

But when I reboot the server, EFS does not get mounted, and I save to remount it again

What should I do here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm posting here a more detailed solution since this thread seems to show up near the top for related queries from search engine.

There are two methods to mount an Amazon EFS: "Amazon EFS mount helper" (*amazon-efs-utils*) and "NFS client" (*nfs-utils*).

Examples below shows how to mount manually and automatically with each method. Before using, replace the text  *[value]*  with your own values.

==============================

===============

Mounting with "Amazon EFS mount helper"

===============

To mount with "Amazon EFS mount helper" **manually**, you **issue** the following command format into **CLI**:

```
sudo mount -t efs [fs-XXXXXXXX]:/ /path/to/mount/dir
```

=====

To mount with "Amazon EFS mount helper" **automatically**, you **insert** the following line into **/etc/fstab**

```
[fs-XXXXXXXX]:/ /path/to/mount/dir efs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

===============

Mounting with "NFS client"

===============

To mount with "NFS client" **manually**, you **issue** either of the following command format into **CLI**:

Use the command instruction given from "Amazon EC2 mount instructions (from local VPC)" when you click in to view the `Elastic File System ID` in question under EFS Web Console.

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=XXXXXXX,wsize=XXXXXXX,hard,timeo=XXX,retrans=X,noresvport [fs-XXXXXXXX].efs.[REGION].amazonaws.com:/ /path/to/mount/dir
```

OR

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o defaults,_netdev [fs-XXXXXXXX].efs.[REGION].amazonaws.com:/ /path/to/mount/dir
```

=====

To mount with "NFS client" **automatically**, you **insert** the following line into **/etc/fstab**

```
[fs-XXXXXXXX].efs.[REGION].amazonaws.com:/ /path/to/mount/dir nfs4 defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

==============================

Given the above example format, do you notice your problem?

You *thought* you've "Amazon EFS mount helper" installed, but based on the manual mount command format you posted in your first comment reply (not opening post), you actually only have "NFS client" installed on your system. You were using "Amazon EFS mount helper" format inside /etc/fstab to auto mount, but the manual mount command that worked for you is in "NFS client" format. Since your system doesn't have "Amazon EFS mount helper" installed, it doesn't understand the auto mount format inside /etc/fstab so auto mount it doesn't work for you.

The manual mount command you posted above that worked for you is only for "NFS client", not for "Amazon EFS mount helper".

> mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1 ...

Notice the `-t` parameter above is `nfs4`, which is the format for "NFS client". If you were using "Amazon EFS mount helper", the `-t` parameter should be `efs`.

To solve the problem, you can use either Amazon EFS mount helper (`amazon-efs-utils`) or NFS client (`nfs-utils`), but the command format (in CLI or /etc/fstab) and the mount client being used should be consistent.

In other words:

"Amazon EFS mount helper" <=> `efs` in both CLI and /etc/fstab

"NFS client" <=> `nfs4` in both CLI and /etc/fstab

==============================

Installation instructions for mount client software:

===============

If you want to use "Amazon EFS mount helper", use the following installation instructions for Amazon Linux and Other Distros:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/using-amazon-efs-utils.html

=====

If you want to use "NFS client", use the following installation instructions on your EC2 instance:

On a Red Hat Enterprise Linux or SUSE Linux instance, including Amazon Linux, use this command:

```
sudo yum install -y nfs-utils
```

On an Ubuntu instance, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

==============================

Once you have the mount client software installed, use the corresponding mounting instructions posted above.

Comment: Isn't using a specific region with nfs option against HA? I thought aws maintains multiple instances of efs on different regions?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this using NFS4, please follow the instructions below:

On your AWS account, notice the following:

1) Go to your EFS management screen, you should your EFS_WHATEVER... and there is a small triangle next to it, click down to expand.

2) Notice there is a "DNS Name" right in the middle of the screen, it will say something like: "fs-1234567c.efs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com", note that down, this is your mounting point that we will use later on.

3) By default, if you have just created the new instance, then you must allow it to be seen by your servers, trying to connect will freeze since the firewall is blocking your connection. to allow this scroll down until you see your security group, this is something like sg-abcdef

4) Go into your EC2 servers, select the server that you want it to access your EFS and then click on its "security groups", it should take you into the security groups management screen, note down it's security group ID (this is something sg-12345)

4) Now, clear the filter of your VPC management screen to see all of the SGs...

5) Enter your EFS security group (i.e. sg-abcdef) and click the search button, this should bring up the EFS ACL

6) Click on "Inbound Rules" -> EDIT..

7) Click "ADD" and select "EFS" from the list, enter your server's SG (i.e. sg-12345) and describe it as "Server XXX access" if you like.

8) Now the server should be able to see the EFS Mount,

9) Go into your server and install the necessary components by running as ROOT:

apt-get install nfs-common

10) Now, to test the MOUNT, create a new directory... something like: mkdir /mnt/heider

11) Mount the FS using the following command:

mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport fs-1234567c.efs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/heider

Please note that your fs-12345c..... is taken from your DNS name as mentioned above.

12) If this work then great, move to the next step, otherwise revise the above to see if you missed anything.

13) Now to auto-mount this, you need to:

14) Edit /etc/fstab

15) Add the following:

fs-1234567c.efs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:/   /mnt/heider nfs4    defaults,_netdev    0 0

16) Save the file and exit

17) in Linux command shell type: 
mount -a

this will test the mounting, if it's mounted then great, rebooting would auto-mount it.

18) This should auto-mount.

19) Reboot to test, all should be there.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the efs file system type, I believe you need to have the amazon-efs-utils package installed.  This will install the additional dependencies.

Comment: i have that installed.. after reboot, i can login to the server and run the following `mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport {EFS-TARGETIP}:/ efs` and it works fine

Comment: if the fstab is right, it should mount with mount -a - does that work?

Answer (score -1):

Anyone who has this issue,

instead of

```
fs-xxxxxxxx:/ /mnt/efs efs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

use

```
{target_ip}:/ /mnt/efs nfs4 defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

This works fine for me, and it auto mounts on the newly created instances

Comment: Using the IP directly instead of DNS means that you won't make any use of the HA provided by AWS. It's recommended to use mount targets https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs.html.

Comment: What do you mean by HA? Unfortunately the only way I could mount it was using the IP, otherwise it gives this error: check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/efs/mount-dns-name for more detail.
Attempting to lookup mount target ip address using botocore. Failed to import necessary dependency botocore, please install botocore first.

Comment: The ID was right, and the target was there... even I installed botocore, and there was still an issue with the IP.